# Error when running retrain.py during retraining for image classifier based on tensorflow for poets

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, docker, tensorflow

I am learning the "[TensorFlow for Poets](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/?utm_campaign=chrome_series_machinelearning_063016&utm_source=gdev&utm_medium=yt-desc#4)" tutorial.

I am getting stuck on the retraining step, where for some reason the retrain.py command (along with the other 4 lines of code attached to it) encounters errors.

I'm thinking it might be a simple fix. I am able to follow the codelab tutorial through each step succesfully until the step with the following command:

```
# python tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py \
--bottleneck_dir=/tf_files/bottlenecks \
--how_many_training_steps 500 \
--model_dir=/tf_files/inception \
--output_graph=/tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \
--output_labels=/tf_files/retrained_labels.txt \
--image_dir /tf_files/flower_photos
```

I enter this into my command line in my Docker terminal and this is the error:
     root@3333e49b2f82:/tensorflow# python          tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py \

> --bottleneck_dir=/tf_files/bottlenecks \
>   --how_many_training_steps 500 \
>   --model_dir=/tf_files/inception \
>   --output_graph=/tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \
>   --output_labels=/tf_files/retrained_labels.txt \
>   --image_dir /tf_files/flower_photos
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 1012, in         
>                tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
>             File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-         packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 43, in run
>           sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
>         File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 751, in main
>           maybe_download_and_extract()
>         File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 313, in    maybe_download_and_extract
>           tarfile.open(filepath, 'r:gz').extractall(dest_directory)
>         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 2051, in extractall
>           self.extract(tarinfo, path)
>         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 2088, in extract
>           self._extract_member(tarinfo, os.path.join(path, tarinfo.name))
>         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 2164, in _extract_member
>           self.makefile(tarinfo, targetpath)
>         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 2205, in makefile
>           copyfileobj(source, target)
>         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 265, in copyfileobj
>           shutil.copyfileobj(src, dst)
>         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 49, in copyfileobj
>           buf = fsrc.read(length)
>         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 818, in read
>           buf += self.fileobj.read(size - len(buf))
>         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 736, in read
>           return self.readnormal(size)
>         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 745, in readnormal
>           return self.fileobj.read(size)
>         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 261, in read
>           self._read(readsize)
>         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 308, in _read
>           self._read_eof()
>         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 347, in _read_eof
>           hex(self.crc)))
>       IOError: CRC check failed 0x76f1f85e != 0x6caceac0L
>       root@3333e49b2f82:/tensorflow#

The only thing I can think of based on these errors is that it has something to do with python2.7? I have both python2.7 and 3.5 installed on my machine (Macbook air) and I'm not sure if this is somehow a problem for Docker or tensorflow...

Anyways any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A CRC error indicates that some data in your compressed file is damaged.

Actually it is happening because previous time while you are running this command you left somewhere in the middle(this was my case) which resulted in partial downloaded inception files. So when you are running this again, it checks the CRC with the previous partially downloaded one which don't match.

**Solution:**
I deleted the previous downloaded one to avoid anomaly during this time command execution.

The downloaded inception files will be in   **/tf_file**  (if you are naming everything as per the tutorial).

So go to **/tf_files** and delete the partially downloaded inception/ directory.

```
rm -rf /inception
```

Come back to **/tensorflow** and run the command again.